# How to display many to many related objects as comma separated list

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between two models:

```
class CouncilDistrict(models.Model):
    district = models.IntegerField('council district')
    zoning_case = models.ManyToManyField('ZoningCase')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.district)
```

and

```
class ZoningCase(models.Model):
    accepted_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='employee_case_acceptedby')
    acres = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    ...
```

Depending on whether a ZoningCase is being edited or not, I want to change how the related council districts are displayed.  If editing, I use a SelectMultiple widget, and that works fine.  When not editing, though, I want to display the list of CouncilDistrict objects as a comma separated list in a TextInput.  That sort of works.

My problem, and question, is that the display in the TextInput shows:

```
[<CouncilDistrict: 1>, <CouncilDistrict: 3>...
```

and not

```
1, 3
```

How do I get only the district field to display, not the model name and district?  Thanks.

Edit: View and template, as requested, with many extraneous fields removed

View:

```
def view_case(request, aCaseId):
    zc = ZoningCase.objects.get(pk=aCaseId)
    form = ViewZoningCaseForm({'id':zc.id,
                           'accepted_by':zc.accepted_by,
                           'acres':zc.acres,
                           'council_districts':CouncilDistrict.objects.filter(zoning_case=zc),
                           'zrt_date':format_date(zc.zrt_date)
                           })
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form, 'case_number':zc.case_number, 'case_id':zc.id, 'editing':False})
    return render_to_response('viewZoningCase.html', variables)
```

Form:

```
class ViewZoningCaseForm(forms.Form):
    council_districts = forms.CharField(label='Council Districts', required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    zrt_date = forms.DateField(label='ZRT Date', required=False, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}), input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d'])
    acres = forms.DecimalField(label='Size of Request', required=False, max_digits=10, decimal_places=4, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    accepted_by = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.none(), required=False, label='Accepted By', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'readonly':'readonly', 'disabled':True}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super (ViewZoningCaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_be_zoning_planner')
    self.fields['accepted_by'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(user__user_permissions=perm)
```

Template (very basic at this point - this is preliminary to get mgt approval):

```
{% block content %}
<div id="zoningCaseDiv">
    <form method="post" action="." id="zoningCaseForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="tab-1">
                <table id="zoningCaseDetailsTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{form.case_number.label_tag}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.case_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.gis_case_id.label_tag}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.gis_case_id}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{form.closed.label_tag}}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.closed }}</td>
                    <td>{{form.council_districts.label_tag}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.council_districts}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please post view/template for that input field.

Comment: In posting requested, code, I noticed I was using a CharField in my Form, not a ModelMultipleChoiceField.  Changing that, I'm now getting closer.  It displays [1, 3], so at least the model name is gone.  How do I remove the brackets?